# How to update foreign keys in single one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update foreign keys into a table named **User** where foreign keys refer to a **Project** table, a **Group** table.
The user belongs to a project, within a group, the group are defined to the project level. The detailed user information are also stored into a table **ToolUser**

The create statement for the User table is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDproject] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDtoolUser] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDgroup] [int] NOT NULL,
    [datemodified] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
```

- **IDproject** is FK for ID in **Project** table
- **IDtoolUser** is FK for ID in **ToolUser** table
- **IDgroup** is FK for ID in **Group** table

The update I want to perform consist in changing the group the user is assigned to which requires to resolve the project ID, the group ID before updating the groupID in the **User** table

I came up with a solution where the group id is calculed with a function, **[dbo].[IDofGroup]**, and used into an UPDATE statement as following

```
UPDATE [dbo].[User] 
SET IDgroup = [dbo].[IDofGroup]('TESTPROJ','none')
FROM [dbo].[User] as u
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] g
        ON g.[ID]= u.[IDgroup] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Project] p 
        ON p.[ID]= u.[IDproject]
        AND p.[name] ='TESTPROJ'
WHERE g.[name] = 'TESTGROUP'
GO
```

The function IDofGroup itself performs couple SELECT to resolve project ID and group ID as following

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IDofGroup]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @ProjectName as varchar(max),
    @GroupName as varchar(max)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ProjectID int, @ResultID int
    SET @ResultID=0

    -- get project ID for @ProjectName
    SELECT @ProjectID= ID 
    FROM [dbo].[Project] 
    WHERE [name]=@ProjectName

    -- find id fro group which name is @GroupName and project ID @ProjectID
    SELECT @ResultID= ID 
    FROM [dbo].[Group] 
    WHERE [IDproject]=@ProjectID
    AND [name]=@GroupName

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultID

END
```

I m wondering if there any way to perform the UPDATE with some kind of JOIN in a single UPDATE statement w/o the need of using of function IDofGroup or other SELECT statements before the UPDATE statement

Comment: On your current `Update` statement, what will the `INNER JOIN`s get you now, without using the function? Turn that into a `Select` statement to get the result you need. Then turn it back into an `Update` statement.

Comment: it is true I could pull verything out of the function and execute couple SELECT statement before. The function was just convenient to be reused. Adding these couple SELECT into the UPDATE is the difficulty I am having and why I am asking 'how to?' It seems adding an INNER JOIN makes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE u
SET IDgroup = g1.[ID]
FROM [dbo].[User] as u
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Project] p 
        ON p.[ID]= u.[IDproject]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] g
        ON g.[ID]= u.[IDgroup] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] g1
        ON g.[IDproject] = g1.[IDproject]
WHERE p.[name] ='TESTPROJ'
AND g.[name] = 'TESTGROUP'
AND g1.[name] = 'none'
```

Comment: Instead of `UPDATE [dbo].[User]` just use `UPDATE u`.